# Animation Scale Arc by Angle

Tags: android, animation, layout

My task is Drawing a Circle Diagram.
I have 4 arcs.
On each arc, I have 2 values to make View Animate.

this image

[image]

will show you more detail.

Can Anyone Suggest me the Animation should I use for each value?
And how can I make it Animate by Specific Angle?

Edit: I upload .gif file for more detail.

[image]

Comment: If I made a mistake or my question was not clear, please recommend so I can improve next time. Don't just downvote, I don't know what I am wrong :(

Comment: That is the problem I faced. I don't know the way I should use to draw arc  in which I can control scale animation easily.
Actually, I am just a junior, I have no idea about this, I just begin with ObjectAnimator 1 week ago. So I need some keywords can resolve the problem.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, maybe I should use "My task is drawing a Circle Diagram"

Comment: Thank you, I will study about Cabvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom View and a custom animation. Override the `applyTransformation()` Method in the custom Animation to apply the transformation.

```
public class ArcView extends View {

    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRect;
    private float arcAngle;

    public ArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

        // Set Angle to 0 initially or whatever you want
        arcAngle = 0;

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRect = new RectF(2, 2, 78, 78);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawArc(mRect, 90, arcAngle, false, mPaint);
    }

    public float getArcAngle() {
        return arcAngle;
    }

    public void setArcAngle(float arcAngle) {
        this.arcAngle = arcAngle;
    }
}
```

And here is how your animation Class looks like

```
public class ArcAngleAnimation extends Animation {

    private ArcView arcView;

    private float oldAngle;
    private float newAngle;

    public ArcAngleAnimation(ArcView arcView, int newAngle) {
        this.oldAngle = arcView.getArcAngle();
        this.newAngle = newAngle;
        this.arcView = arcView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        float angle = oldAngle + ((newAngle - oldAngle) * interpolatedTime);

        arcView.setArcAngle(angle);
        arcView.requestLayout();
    }

    public void setNewAngle(int newAngle){
        this.newAngle = newAngle;
    }

    public void setOldAngle(float oldAngle) {
        this.oldAngle = oldAngle;
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is apply animation and run it in your activity or fragment

```
ArcView view = (ArcView) findViewById(R.id.arc_view);
ArcAngleAnimation arcAnimation;
arcAnimation = new ArcAngleAnimation(view, 30);
arcAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
arcAnimation.setDuration(200);
view.startAnimation(arcAnimation);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
But what is leftAnim in arcAnimation = new ArcAngleAnimation(leftAnim, 30); ?

Comment: my bad, it should have been `view` the ArcView object that was declared. Edited the answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it not work.
The layout is<br/>

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.example.thiendn.tempproject.ArcView
        android:id="@+id/arc_view"
        android:src="@drawable/test_smile"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
</LinearLayout>`